# Were exactly did I go wrong in rationalizing denominator?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The question is to rationalize: $\frac{\sqrt5}{\sqrt10 - \sqrt5}$

I stopped at $\sqrt50 + 1$ after multiplying by the conjugate and cancelling out everything because I knew at this point my answer is wrong. The correct answer should be $\sqrt 2 + 1$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\frac{\sqrt5}{\sqrt10 - \sqrt5}=\frac{\sqrt5}{\sqrt{10} - \sqrt5} \times\frac{\sqrt{10} + \sqrt5}{\sqrt{10} + \sqrt5}=\frac{\sqrt5 (\sqrt{10} + \sqrt5)}{10-5}=\frac{\sqrt{10} + \sqrt5}{\sqrt5}=\sqrt2 +1$$

Comment: Can you please explain how you went from the brackets, to the one after? root 5 * 10 = root 50..I don't see it anywhere after.

Comment: Well $\dfrac{\sqrt{5}(\sqrt{10} + \sqrt{5} )}{10-5}=\dfrac{\sqrt{5}(\sqrt{10} + \sqrt{5} )}{5}=\dfrac{(\sqrt{10} + \sqrt{5} )}{\sqrt{5}}$ where on the last step both the numerator and denominator have been divided by $\sqrt{5}$

Comment: Wow, I didn't know that 5 /root 5 = root5...thanks

Comment: But I am sure that you know that $\sqrt 5 \sqrt 5=5$; then you know that $\frac{5}{\sqrt 5}=\sqrt 5$. I am glad of having been of some help to you. Cheers :-)

Answer (score 1):

For positive real $a,b$ $\displaystyle\sqrt{ab}=\sqrt a\cdot\sqrt b$

$$\implies\frac{\sqrt5}{\sqrt{10}-\sqrt5}=\frac{\sqrt5}{\sqrt5(\sqrt2-1)}=\frac{\sqrt2+1}{(\sqrt2)^2-1^2}$$

Answer (score 1):

Here are the steps
$$
\frac{\sqrt{5}}{\sqrt{10}-\sqrt{5}}= \frac{\sqrt{5}}{\sqrt{2}\sqrt{5}-\sqrt{5}}= \frac{\sqrt{5}}{\sqrt{5}\left(\sqrt{2}-1\right)}= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}-1}\times \frac{\sqrt{2}+1}{\sqrt{2}+1}=\ \frac{\sqrt{2}+1}{2-1}=\sqrt{2}+1
$$

Answer (score 0):

First note that $\sqrt{10}=\sqrt{5}\cdot\sqrt{2}$, then remove $\sqrt{5}$ as a factor from the top & bottom.

Then multiply the fraction by $\frac{\sqrt{2}+1}{\sqrt{2}+1}$. Hope I helped.